# Can I set max render time instead of samples?

Tags: rendering

Is there a way to set max render time instead of max render samples?

Can i tell blender to render for example for ten minutes, so that it reaches the best quality it can achieve in 10 minutes?
I know a lot of render engines has this option, but i couldn't find it in cycles.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no such an option for it now (Good feature for sure). The similar way is to enable **progressive refine** in your Scene Performance panel.

[image]

It will treat all render area as a chunk, which give you the ability to manually stop at the point you think your image is well enough.

Here is the official [description](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html#tiles):

> #### Progressive Refine
>
> Instead of rendering each tile until it has
> finished every sample, refine the whole image progressively. Note that
> progressive rendering is slightly slower than tiled rendering, but
> time can be saved by manually stopping the render when the noise level
> is low enough.
>
> For rendering animations it is best to disable this feature, as
> stopping a frame early is not possible.

Note: If you found out that Progressive Refine check box is grey out. Then check if you are using Denoising option in Scene Render Layer. You cannot use them simultaneously.

Comment: Just a few opinion for developer: If we know the tiles need to be rendered. Can't we just stop at the time that sum up to user preferred time? Using timer or something else and emit stop event at each tile is done?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still seeking an answer to this, the LuxCoreRender add-on DOES allow you to set a time limit for rendering. And I believe I read that the upcoming Cycles-X release will allow for pausing of rendering. I really hope this will also address the timed rendering option, too.